# How to move object on curve along X/Z axes without object's X-scale compressing

Tags: objects, bezier-curves, transforms, proportional-editing, compression

(as my first Stack Exchange question) I'm hoping to determine how to keep my object's proportions intact while it move forward and up along a X/Z curve. I realize the curve shortens the object's path in relation to the world path, as I can see the object's origin still moving along the X-axis in the distance, but how can I keep the proportions relative to the object intact?

I've created the shape of the cube in Edit Mode, sectioning the object with loop cuts.
Then applied the curve modifier, moving the object along the curve on the x-axis in object mode...

The end results would be similar to a piece of paper going through a home printer (before/after images below).

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe switch your curve to Edit mode, select all and right click > Set Curve Radius > type 1 and Enter? You may have changed the vertices radius when you've applied the scale of your curve...

Comment: hi, the curve radius for the path seems to be set to 1

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: you need to share the URL  ;)

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/e97bd97d5a0b430d99808bc723d3737d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scale of your curve (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode)